# Where can I find (Path in the bundle) the User create/edit screen source?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am just trying to find the front end source code for user creation and edit pages. But I tried search by different label text and ID's but no use. Can anyone please tell me the path for user add and edit page source files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the URL is something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/group/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=125&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&refererPlid=15595&_125_redirect=%2Fgroup%2Fcontrol_panel%3FrefererPlid%3D15595&_125_struts_action=%2Fusers_admin%2Fedit_user
```

Searching in struts configurations you can see that `struts_action=/users_admin/edit_user` should refer to jsp file `edit_user.jsp`

That file is located in `users_admin`... so the path you are seeking should be `html/portlet/users_admin` inside `portal-web` project.

[This](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/edit_user.jsp) is on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell the path for the action classes of edit_user.jsp on GItHub.

Comment: As I said, everything is in Struts configuration file: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml searching for /users_admin/edit_user you can find the declaration <action path="/users_admin/edit_user" type="com.liferay.portlet.usersadmin.action.EditUserAction"> containing the action name also; always on GitHub this is the link: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/usersadmin/action/EditUserAction.java

Comment: Thank you I have my last query , In which file I can find the following declarations, <action path="/users_admin/edit_user" type="com.liferay.portlet.usersadmin.action.EditUserAction">

Comment: Read carefully my previous answer: there is the link to that file at the beginning.